# Android Device Support Lifecycles

Tags: android

A key consideration for most computer platforms is the availability of security patches for vulnerabilities which inevitably arise with them.

Are there any available resources which provide information on what Android security issues have been patched/not patched for a given device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it tracks all the issues and not a security issues resource, you can search the issues in Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker for security issues of a given device.

Here is the [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).